# Where are Outlook 2010 Email Settings, not the pst data files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've found all my Outlook data files which contain all my emails at the following paths:

```
C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
C:\Users\C\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook
and
C:\Users\C\My Documents\Outlook Files\
```

I've migrated all these and copied it to my new machine at the same directories however my configuration is not there! None of my email pop/smtp settings are there, only the pst is loaded with my emails but all other configuration is gone, where precisely is that configuration stored?

Comment: Have you checked the registry?  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook` seems like a good place to look, or you could search the entire registry for data that you're looking for (e.g., your server name).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010354943.aspx) tells the locations of the files but there is not a good way to transfer your account settings with these files. Try [Windows Easy Transfer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928634).